# Rows not moving upwards in looped content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, layout, rows

Hi I am new user to Bootstrap (and coding), I have some looped content which takes an image and text for each loop (of different image heights and text lengths) to create 4 columns. But the result does not flow how I would like it too - see image example [image shows how img/text layout in 4 columns] Any help or advice greatly appreciated!

Here's the code example;

```
<div class="container-fluid bg-3 text-center">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3">
  <some loop code which gets 1 image and 1 set of text>
  </loop>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to start a new row every fourth iteration of your loop..

```
$i = 0; //Count

//Start your loops

if($i % 4 === 0) {
 echo '</div><div class="row">';
}

++$i;
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree that you should start with a row every 4th turn but you should also close the end tag of the div properly
Here is the sample code

```
   var i = 0;
for(your logic){
if( i%4 === 0 {
  Append <div class="row">
}
elseif(i%4 !== 0 && i%4 !==3){ 
    Append the following code
 <div class="col-sm-3">
      The image should be here
  </div>

  }     
else if( i%4=== 3){
  Append </div>
}

}
```

Comment: You are right of course, the div was closed properly further down in the actual code - thanks so much for answering - I will check it out!

Comment: I think I did close the div properly in my answer above?

Comment: In your code, your loop is inside the divs with classes row and col-sm-3. But in order to get the required result they should be inside the loop as show in my answer.

Comment: And by the "Close the end tag properly" I meant that it should be closed properly inside the logic as shown in the answer